# How to push events to a C# client from an Azure Service Fabric Service?

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to push an event from something happening in one of my services, hosted on a Service Fabric Cluster, to a C# client application.

Whilst communicating events within my cluster seems possible, (I am looking at using this https://service-fabric-pub-sub.socreate.it/), I cannot find a way to relay events from my Service's API Gateway back to the client application (after they have subscribed).

I have tried to look into setting up web sockets, and looked at Signal R, but I am not sure that these are the correct tools for what I am trying to achieve. Any suggestions of where to start looking would be a great help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The library you have linked is for pub/sub messaging within the SF cluster.  If you need to push these events to the client, rather than poll the server for new events on a regular basis, then it does sound like websockets would work well for this requirement.  For websockets - there are many different ways that this can be achieved.  I have documented one solution [here](https://undocumented.dev/signalr-scaleout-using-service-fabric-actor-events/), however the [Azure SignalR](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/signalr-service/) service would be simpler to setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pub Sub library you're looking at, is for messaging **inside** the cluster, without introducing external dependencies.

If you want to send messages to applications **outside** of the cluster, you should use a message queue, like [Azure Service Bus Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues).

For receiving messages from the C# client within the cluster, you can use [this library or source code](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.ServiceBus), that implements a `ICommunicationListener`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, will have a look into Azure Service Bus Queues. I have seen Rabbit MQ mentioned quite often as well which I am hoping may also be suitable. If I understand correctly I should be able to setup my Message Queue on a server and my services could send messages to the queue - and client applications may subscribe to messages from the message queue so they get notified when a message is sent by a service? Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: Yes, Rabbit MQ will work, except that you'd have to host it yourself. Big advantages of Azure Service Bus are that it's hosted for you, high available, and can scale. If you're already running Service Fabric inside Azure, adding it should be easy.